# Remove html after some point in Beautilful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a trouble. My aim is to parse the data until some moment. Then, I want to stop parsing.

```
        <span itemprop="address">
         Some address
        </span>
        <i class="fa fa-signal">
        </i>
        ...
       </p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="search_pagination" id="pagination">
      <ul class="pagination">
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
   <div class="panel" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPSideBar">
    <h2 class="heading_a" itemprop="name">
     Top-10 today
    </h2> #a lot of tags after that moment
```

I want to get all the values from `<span itemprop="address">` (there are a lot of them before) until the moment `Top-10 today`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually let `BeautifulSoup` [parse only the tags you are interested in via `SoupStrainer`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

only_addresses = SoupStrainer("span", itemprop="address")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser", parse_only=only_addresses)
```

If you though have some "addresses" before the "Top-10 today" and some after but you are interested in those coming before it, you can make a custom [searching function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function):

```
def search_addresses(tag):
    return tag.name == "span" and tag.get("itemprop") == "address" and \
           tag.find_next("h2", text=lambda text: text and "Top-10 today" in text)

addresses = soup.find_all(search_addresses)
```

It does not look trivial, but the idea is simple - we are using [`find_next()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) for every "address" to check if "Top-10 today" heading exists after it.